# Unable to receive callback from DocuSign for failed email delivery

Tags: docusignapi

We are trying to get a callback from DocuSign to our application when an email failed to be delivered to a signer.

So far, we have set up an ‘AutoResponded’ listener, but did not manage to get a callback.
In our developer account admin settings, we have also enabled following settings:

- Account > Updates: Send Individual Messages [Switched status to
  Active]
  [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzI1w.png)
- Integrations > Connect: In our custom configuration, under
  Trigger Events, we have enabled Recipient Delivery Failed [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IeCn.png)

Any advise if we need to enable any other setting? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting which needs to be enabled and it is available only in back-end in DocuSign. You need to create a ticket through our [support center](https://support.docusign.com/) provide your account number and ask support to enable it.

> You need to be admin on the account to request this change

Comment: Hi Ivan, I am unable to open a ticket through the support center (Cannot login). Note that my DocuSign account is a developer account. Is there a different portal to log a case for developer accounts?

Comment: please email go-live@docusign.com with reference to this question and case 07333403